Django manage.py no module named 'storages'
I have a problem with trying to run my 'python manage.py makemigrations' command. I guess it has something to do with the core installation of Django itself. I am running on a Windows Visual Code running Ubuntu 24.04 in WSL with Python 3.12.3 running.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kevin/Django_fans/djfans/manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/kevin/Django_fans/djfans/manage.py", line 19, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/kevin/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/kevin/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 416, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/kevin/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/kevin/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/kevin/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 193, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1324, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'storages'


As this is a programming-related question which isn't really related to Ubuntu - which AskUbuntu is about - please consider raising the question at StackOverflow, which is the right platform for these types of questions.
